# How can I make this Observable more reusable?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

This is an observable sequence that retrieves paginated data from a web service. Each web service response contains a `nextRecordsUrl` that indicates where to get the next set of records. What is the best way to convert this Observable to something more reusable?

Web services setup:

```
var auth = new AuthenticationClient ();
await auth.UsernamePasswordAsync (consumerKey, consumerSecret, userName, password + passwordSecurityToken);
var forceClient = new ForceClient (auth.InstanceUrl, auth.AccessToken, auth.ApiVersion);
```

The Observable:

```
var observable = Observable.Create<QueryResult<Account>> (async (IObserver<QueryResult<Account>> o) =>
{
    try
    {
        var queryResult = await forceClient.QueryAsync<Account> ("SELECT Id, Name from Account");
        if (queryResult != null)
        {
            o.OnNext (queryResult);

            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (queryResult.nextRecordsUrl))
            {
                queryResult = await forceClient.QueryContinuationAsync<Account> (queryResult.nextRecordsUrl);
                if (queryResult != null)
                {
                    o.OnNext (queryResult);
                }
            }
        }
        o.OnCompleted ();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        o.OnError (ex);
    }

    return () => {};
});
```

Subscribing to the observable and collecting the results:

```
   var accounts = new List<Account> ();
    observable.Subscribe (
        observer => accounts.AddRange (observer.records),
        ex => Console.WriteLine (ex.Message),
        () => {});
```

**EDIT:** Using Brandon's solution I can now generate the list of results with Aggregate

```
List<Account> accounts = await forceClient.QueryPages<Account> ("SELECT Id, Name from Account")
                .Aggregate (new List<Account> (), (list, value) =>
                {
                    list.AddRange (value.records);
                    return list;
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe it or not, the [Rx-Expiremental](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-Experimental/) library (also maintained by MS) has an operator for this called `Expand`. Expand is used to take each element from an observable and run it through a function which produces another observable of the same type. That observable is then flattened in to the original, and each item from that goes through the same process.

Imagine being given a tree node with an observable of child nodes. You could use expand to easily traverse this tree. Since a linked-list is just a constrained version of a tree, and since what you have is effectively a linked list where each node is an observable, you can use expand.

```
public static IObservable<QueryResult<TResult>> QueryPages<TResult>(this ForceClient forceClient, string query)
{
    return Observable.FromAsync(() => forceClient.QueryAsync<TResult>(query))
        .Where(QueryResultIsValid)
        .Expand(result =>
            Observable.FromAsync(() => forceClient.QueryContinuationAsync<TResult>(queryResult.nextRecordsUrl))
                .Where(QueryResultIsValid)
        );
}

public static bool QueryResultIsValid(QueryResult<TResult> result)
{
    return result != null;
}
```

Comment: It traverses in the order each element is yielded, so it will be breadth first, since `(root) -> [c1, c2, c3]`, then `(c1) -> [c11, c12, c13]`, then `(c2) -> [c21, c22, c23]`, etc. Basically it schedules each recursive call in the trampoline manner.

Comment: If you wanted to traverse depth first, you wouldn't actually need expand. Instead, you would use typical in-order, post-order or pre-order traversal, where each node subscribes to it's child nodes. The advantage of expand is that it does not require the nodes to know how to traverse themselves, nor does it need to know how the data is structured - aside from having an observable property on each node.

Comment: I'm getting a "Cannot resolve symbol 'Expand'". BTW I'm on Rx 2.2.4

Comment: My apologies. This is in the `Rx-Experimental` package. It is not in core, yet. There are other useful operators in that library, as well. I typically have all Rx libraries referenced when doing development, as they reduce the amount of boilerplate code. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-Experimental/

Comment: Assuming you could pre-calculate the nextRecordsUrl for all remaining records how would you change the Expand to run in parallel?

Comment: Expand does not run in parallel, not would you need it to if you could per-calculate all of the nextRecordUrls. All you would need to do is use Merge for all requests. Granted, if you wanted to keep them in order, you might need to handle that separately, or with a custom operator.

Answer (score 2):

Is something like this what you are looking for?

```
public static IObservable<QueryResult<TResult>> QueryPages<TResult>(this ForceClient forceClient, string query)
{
    return Observable.Create<QueryResult<T>> (async (observer, token) =>
    {
        // No need for try/catch.  Create() will call OnError if your task fails.
        // Also no need for OnCompleted().  Create() calls it when your task completes
        var queryResult = await forceClient.QueryAsync<TResult> (query);
        while (queryResult != null)
        {
            observer.OnNext (queryResult);

            // check the token *after* we call OnNext
            // because if an observer unsubscribes
            // it typically occurs during the notification
            // e.g. they are using .Take(..) or
            // something.
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryResult.nextRecordsUrl) ||
                token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                break;
            }

            queryResult = await forceClient.QueryContinuationAsync<TResult> (queryResult.nextRecordsUrl);
        }
        // No need to return anything.  Just the Task itself is all that Create() wants.
    }
});

// Usage:
var forceClient = // ...
var foos = forceClient.QueryPages<Foo>("SELECT A, B, C FROM Foo");
```

Notice I switched it to the overload that provides a cancellation token so that you can stop fetching pages if the observer unsubscribes (Your original version would have continued fetching pages even though the observer had stopped listening).  Also note that the async `Create` awaits your `Task` and calls `OnError` or `OnCompleted` for you so you do not need to worry about that most of the time.

Comment: I don't use the async overloads all that often, but do you need an `OnCompleted` before the `break`, or does the `Task` completion handle that for you...

Comment: Also, `Expand` is the idiomatic operator for this use case.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris yes Create() eventually [calls Task.ToObservable](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/develop/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/QueryLanguage.Creation.cs#L49).  I didn't know about `Expand`.  I suppose that would be something like `Observable.FromAsync(()=>c.QueryAsync(query)).Where(q=>q!=null).Expand(q=>q.nextRecordsUrl==null?Observable.Empty():q.QueryContinuationAsync(q.nextRecordsUrl).ToObservable().Where(q=>q!=null))`?

Comment: I've added an answer for `Expand`.